# How to get documentation from Rails generators about type modifiers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation, rails-migrations, rails-generate

In the documentation for [Active Record Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) in Rails 4.2.x, the section [2.3 Passing Modifiers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#passing-modifiers) says:

> Some commonly used type modifiers can be passed directly on the
>   command line. They are enclosed by curly braces and follow the field
>   type:
>
> For instance, running:
>
> $ bin/rails generate migration AddDetailsToProducts
>   'price:decimal{5,2}' supplier:references{polymorphic}
>
> ...
>
> Have a look at the generators help output for further details.

However, running `bundle exec rails generate migration --help` in Rails 4.2.x (in my case 4.2.3) doesn't mention anything about passing type modifiers - I can't even see a single curly brace.

I can see some documentation at [3.5 Column Modifiers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers), but how do I get the documentation referred to as being from the "generators help output"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the inline help describing types modifiers you need to run

```
bundle exec rails generate model --help
```

Also, the help text is coming from here: https://github.com/randoum/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/model/USAGE